# How to make statusbar not transparent (storyboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7-statusbar

I've got a pretty straightforward question and somehow I didn't find an answer on this site yet.
I've got a view with a background a yellow color. I'm displaying content in the view and in order for the statusbar to not conflict with the content, I want the background to be non-transparent and preferably set to specific color.

How do I do this with storyboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see is to add a 20 height view aligned to the top of the view to act as a status bar background.

20 is the current size of the status bar but it's better if u get it programatically.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
```